# websocket сервер, продолжить работу после закрытия терминала

Tags: websocket, консоль

Может вопрос прозвучит глупо.
В общем есть VPS с ubuntu. Решил поиграться с вебсокетами. 
Использую php библиотеку https://github.com/walkor/Workerman. Все завелось с первого раза, прямо аж удивился, что все так просто.

Открываю терминал **php index.php start** и можно обмениваться сообщениями.

Но проблема в том, что если закрыть окно терминала, то и WS сервер так же закроется.

Час гугления, tmux, screen - ничего не получается.

Как закрыть терминал, не закрыв при этом запущенную программу?

И второй вопрос. Есть ли какие либо графические панели для управления websocket серверами? Просто что бы показывал статус, количество подключенных клиентов, кнопки запустить, остановить, перезапустить.

Comment: Что со screen не получается?

Comment: Нужно было заглянуть в документацию. php index.php start -d (Run as daemon mode) и теперь можно закрыть терминал.

Comment: А выключать его потом как? Лучше добавьте systemd-юнит вместо всех этих костылей)

Comment: Как один из плохих вариантов nohup index.php start &

Comment: А можно вэб сервер заставить запускать сокет)